# Non-client area messages in Win32

Tags: winapi

I want my window to close as soon as the mouse hovers on the close button on the non client area. I tried to trap wm_ncmousemove but i could not find the hittest for the close button.
Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HTCLOSE returned after processing WM_NCHITTEST

Answer (score 1):

[WM_NCHITTEST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645618(VS.85).aspx)